# Trying to find a better way to map API JSON to different struct depends on selected category in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, http

My question is about architecting my model, not syntax in my iOS App.

I am getting different JSON data from API, I created a few structs and map JSON API data to them. As you can see in the below code, I use Switch statement to map different type of data BUT I know there can be a better way as I have 10 categories in my iOS App.

On top of that, I would really do not want to do the switch inside my UITableView Delegate and Datasource methods as well.

Any Help is really appreciated... Thank you!

```
import UIKit

// ----------- Category 1 -------------------
struct Category1:Decodable {
let recordID:String?
let Year_when_Started:String?
let Problem_Name:String?
}

// ----------- Category 2 -------------------

struct Category2:Decodable {
let Refused:String?
let Date_Given:String?
let recordID:String?
let Date_when_Next_Due:String?
}


// ------- Category 3 ----------------

struct Category3:Decodable{
    var Address:String?
    var City:String?
    var Date_of_Birth:String?
    var First_Name:String?
    var Gender:String?
    var Last_Name:String?
    var Postal_Code:String?
    var recordID:String?
}


class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {

let selectedCategory:String?


var Category1List = [Category1]()
var Category2List = [Category2]()
var Category3List = [Category3]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // assuming selectedCategory would be "Category1" or "Category2" or "Category3"
    getItemsBySelectedCategory(selectedCategory: selectedCategory!)
}



func getItemsBySelectedCategory(selectedCategory:String) {


    let urlString = "https://localhost/getItemsBySelectedCategory"
    guard let url = URL(string:urlString) else { return }


    var request = URLRequest(url:url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue(auth_token, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
    let bodyData = "categoryName=\(selectedCategory)"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, res, err) in

        do {

            switch(selectedCategory) {

            case "Category1":
                self.Category1List = try JSONDecoder().decode([Category1].self, from: data!)
                break
            case "Category2":
                self.Category2List = try JSONDecoder().decode([Category2].self, from: data!)
                break

            case "Category3":
                self.Category3List = try JSONDecoder().decode([Category3].self, from: data!)
                break

            default:
                return
            }




        } catch let jsonErr {
            print(jsonErr)
        }



        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use enum with associated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums in Swift have a feature called Enum with Associated values, where you can create different cases and for each case you can save some information, in this scenario each case could be a different category and for each category you can save your array of that kind of Category(Category1, Category2, ...).

I created an example of how to use associated values, the logic is wrapped inside the enum Category.

The only downside is that you have to set a global value called `mainCategory` because you have to use this in the decode initializer of the enum.

```
let mainCategory: Category = .category1([])
```

Check the code :) hope it helps.

https://gist.github.com/aguilarpgc/6a9a2c0b924ea87d89851371a2ca0f4b

Comment: I added the url computed property so you have to use in: `let bodyData = "categoryName=\(mainCategory.url)"`

Comment: And for the switch logic in your tableview datasource and delegate you could put that logic inside the `UITableViewCell`. Because it handles different models, as far as I now you will have to use switch but in a save way using the enum Category